# codeigniter A Database Error Occurred

Tags: codeigniter

Can someone help me?

I am a beginner and trying to make wearing CodeIgniter authentication, but when I try to make an error like this

A Database Error Occurred

```
Error Number: 1046
```

No database selected

```
SELECT * FROM (`user`) WHERE `user_username` = 'amanda' AND user_passwordMD5("12345") =

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

thanx

Comment: can you please make sure you have setup database configuration in config/database.php file

Comment: Please refer to the Codeignitor documentation before jumping to the coding.

Comment: did any of the answer work !!!

Comment: thank you for giving advice, I do not have any information about documentnya and practice that the less I understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the **database.php** file in **application/config/**

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypassword';
$db['default']['database'] = 'my_database'; // here is the database selection
```

Comment: I have tried it and then appear again error like this
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to select the specified database: authtentication

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 140

Comment: have you specified the db on database.php

Comment: $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'authtentication';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

sorry

Answer (score 3):

please make sure you have setup database configuration in application/config/database.php file

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'my_database';
```

Comment: thx, I have tried it and then appear again error like this A Database Error Occurred Unable to select the specified database: authtentication Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\system\database\DB_driver.php Line Number: 140

Comment: Please check your MySql Server it's running?

Comment: Make sure your database is exists

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `application/config/database.php` file and change the following line:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

To:

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

This shift to `mysqli` saved by day.

Answer (score 0):

Lost connection to MySQL server during query
Line Number: 337

Answer (score -1):

people who critic here should have not only education but also common sense. they should know also what time I made this comment and what was my reputation score. It is not only about giving an answer but the giving also the suggestion a beginner can pin-point the problem. I could have given the answer but just after posting my comment someone already given answer. Look below - best among anyone given here

```
$config['hostname'] = "localhost";
$config['username'] = "username";
$config['password'] = "password";
$config['database'] = "database";
$config['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$config['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$config['cachedir'] = "";
$config['char_set'] = "utf8";
$config['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```